# Как в коде сделать переход на SplitVC master с detail в коде если оба они в navigation controllere

Tags: xcode, swift, split, navigationcontroller

Основная идея заключается в кастомизации кнопки назад в момент нахождения в detail VC. Но проблема заключается в том, что navigation controller в обоих контролерах не знаю о том, что есть кнопка назад. Так что решил делать кнопку кастомной через код, и не могу никак понять как вызвать из detail VC master VC?
[image: Пример экрана]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут можно сделать такой вариант (если не нужен navigationController для detail ) тогда подойдет такая схема [image: схема] . Добавляете в мейн контроллере екшен который будет брать detail контроллер и пушить его в стек сплит вью 
           `self.splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") , sender: self)`

прописываете сториборд id для detail контроллера. Теперь в навигейшн баре будет обычная кнопка "

`self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

и она будет переводить на мейн контроллер

вот так будет выглядеть навигейшн бар detail контроллера [image: detail]

---

Вот такая схема как у вас 
[image: вот такая схема как у вас]

вот екшн на голубой кнопке `self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

вот екшн для возврата с оранжевого на зеленый `self.splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") , sender: self)`

где *second* - идентификатор нижнего (зеленого) навигейшн контроллера

Comment: Оба навигейшена нужны.

Comment: тогда такой же вариант но прописываете сториборд id не для detail контроллера, а для навигейшн контроллера detail view. но теперь будет такая штука: detail контроллер будет пушится в стек навигейшн контроллера первого мейн вью а весь этот стек пушится в навигейшн контроллер  detail view

Comment: может проще заменить Сплит вью на Tab Bar controller , спрятать бар топа у вас будут два независимых стека контроллеров и вы сможете между мини переключатся через Tab Bar controller. а кнопку вы можете добавлять/убирать через состояние контроллера , в зависимости от того откуда был переход

Comment: Понимаете, дело в том, что я хочу кастомизировать эту кнопку "back", я прочел все что вы написали и это не приближает меня к решению, ведь я не понимаю какой экшен сделать для созданной кнопки назад. self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) - работать там не будет.

Comment: да, не будет а вот self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) будет

Comment: О и правда, работает! Спасибо большое!!! А почему надо именно к  self.navigationController?.navigationController обращаться? Там какая то иерархия навегешн контроллеров?

Comment: Да. Получается что нижний пушится полностью в верхний . А для нижнего рут контроллер это зелёный экран(на моем скрине) потому никакого перехода и не происходило